# Is it acceptable to place the elbows on my thighs and knees during supplication because of tiredness?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, dua

When I perform supplication (dua), I raise my hands but after several minutes my arms feel tired, so in general I feel more comfortable to place my elbows on my thighs or knees.

I still do maintain my hands upward with the only difference that the weight of the arms falls on the thighs and knees. I put my elbows on my thighs and knees so i can feel more comfortable during supplication.

Is this allowed or disliked (Makruh)?

Comment: can you precise what you mean by "supplication" ? Tu you mean just asking God for things ? Or are you talking about a precise ceremonial thing?

Comment: Precisely asking God for something. Like help, mercy  solution of my problems, strengthening of iman, purification of heart, good health and protection from evil

Comment: First of all, I don't understand why do you even think that this disliked or Makruh.?